# What does State Service Application do exactly

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-on-prem, 2016, services

I have to come out now. I have little understanding what we use State Service Application for. I know we need it for InfoPath and some other services. It's something where SharePoint stores user sessions. But can someone share the full list of SharePoint components that require this service? I want to find as much information on it as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we know that  it store temporary data across related HTTP requests in a SQL Server database. All the components use that kind of thing required it.Couple of things I know

- publishing will not work I.e publish workflow, publish page
- The State Service must be properly configured for the Search Administration Crawl and Query Health Reports to function properly.
- some Visio service component
- chart web part